# Strange lubridate behaviour when calculating time in months

Tags: lubridate

I am trying to calculate the time between two dates in months, and in particular I am interested in whether that time is < 18 months.  I get conflicting results using lubridate.

At first, I used e.g.

`lubridate::interval("2015-05-11", "2016-11-09")/months(1)`

which returns a value of 17.935 months.  But my colleague did this calculation manually and came up with a slightly different value (and importantly > 18 months).

After some investigation, I found that if I coerce both intervals in the above formula to numeric:

`as.numeric(lubridate::interval("2015-05-11", "2016-11-09"))/as.numeric(months(1))`

I get the same value as my colleague, which is 18.004.

But my question is: why does coercing to numeric make this difference?  I would expect it to make no difference.